# margin lost when use custom-component in Angular

Tags: html, css, angular

Hello I have a parent flex box and 2 childs with 100% width.

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <app-user></app-user>
  <div class="text">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Delectus
    laboriosam incidunt necessitatibus optio id cumque velit nam deserunt
    dolorem. Dolorum asperiores corporis reiciendis veniam, porro temporibus
    obcaecati distinctio illo. Nihil.
  </div>
</div>
```

My margin in `<app-user>` not working , due to the 100% width of parent. I need to fix the 100% width of my `.sidebar` element to keep the width and also I need a margin to take `.text` little bit away from my first element
[link to code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/create-a-basic-angular-component-es4c2h?file=src/app/example/user.component.css)

**app-user**

```
<div class="sidebar">
    sidebar
    <img
    src="https://cdn.oneesports.gg/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/Dota2_InvokerHeader-1024x683.jpg"
    alt=""
  />
</div>
```

**css**

```
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
}


.sidebar {
  max-width: 400px;
  width: 100%;
  margin-right: 32px;
}

.sidebar img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

**UPD 1**
If I move styles from `.sidebar` directly to `app-user` in browser it works perfect , but I dont want to use `:host` styles in css. As in produciton I have a big project

Answer (score 0):

You can use calc() function documented here :
https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/CSS/calc()

So you can remove the margin from your .sidebar class
and add this css lines to your app.component.css :

`.wrapper .text { width: calc(100% - 32px); margin-left: 32px; }`

And [here is your link code that I modified](https://stackblitz.com/edit/create-a-basic-angular-component-gjrqfw?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.css)